# racket/scheme Checking for struture equality

Tags: racket

Ok I need some help with thinking through this conceputally.
I need to check if a list and another list is structurally equal.

For example:

(a (bc) de)) is the same as (f (gh) ij)), because they have the same structure.

Now cleary the base case will be if both list are empty they are structurally equal.

The recursive case on the other hand I'm not sure where to start.

Some ideas:

Well we are not going to care if the elements are == to each other because that doesn't matter. We just care in the structure. I do know we will car down the list and recursively call the function with the cdr of the list.

The part that confuses me is how do you determine wheter an atom or sublist has the same structure?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting there.  In the (free, online, excellent) textbook, this falls into section 17.3, "Processing two lists simultaneously: Case 3". I suggest you take a look.

http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-1.html#node_toc_node_sec_17.3

One caveat: it looks like the data definition you're working with is "s-expression", which you can state like this:

```
;; an s-expression is either
;; - the empty list, or
;; - (cons symbol s-expression), or
;; - (cons s-expression s-expression)
```

Since this data definition has three cases, there are nine possibilities when considering two of them.

John Clements

(Yes, you could reduce the number of cases by embedding the data in the more general one that includes improper lists. Doesn't sound like a good idea to me.)

Comment: Ok so cons, puts two s expressions together, how does this help us?

Comment: How about this idea, if we cons together a list and it has the same length then they are structurally equal?

Comment: My comments are probably only going to make sense in the context of HtDP (the textbook referenced above).  Your problem (do two s-expressions have the same shape) requires you to consider two values, each of which has three possible shapes. That gives rise to nine possible combinations. Of those, three of them (both are empty, both are (cons symbol s-exp), both are (cons s-exp s-exp)) will require additional sub-checks (following the design recipe), and the other six will lead to failure.

Comment: Once again, though: I don't believe that my comments or terminology are going to make sense outside of HtDP. My two cents.